# Construction of Stochastic integration with respect to levy processes

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, levy-processes

I am asking if anyone could recommand me a book containing the rigorous construction of stochastic integral with respect to levy processes(as integrators). Many thanks!

Comment: Lévy processes are particular examples of semimartingales, and therefore you can pick any book which explains stochastic integration with respect to semimartingales...

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the book: D. Applebaum, *Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus*, 2nd Ed, Cambridge University Press, 2005.

Comment: Many thanks for your help